# Pandas, Pivot_Table: Format and sum field from CSV source data file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pivot-table

I'm trying to format a value field from my source data file from currency to float and sum it as part of my pivot table value field. The source file is formatted as CSV. I have the code setup for the pivot using pandas, but having difficulty converting the currency formatted field to float. Right now, if I were to run this code, the pivot formats correctly by column and row, but the value field is messy.

Any ideas on a simple method to format the currency field? I know I need to remove the $ and "," and trim that last space out, but just not sure how --  Example data and code so far below:

**Code:**

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('Example Data.csv')
data = df.pivot_table(index="State",values="Revenue",aggfunc=np.sum)
print data
```

**Data Set:**

```
State,Revenue
CT,"$10,000.00 "
MA,"$20,000.00 "
MA,"$40,000.00 "
MA,"$80,000.00 "
CT,"$160,000.00 "
NY,"$320,000.00 "
NJ,"$640,000.00 "
NJ,"$1,280,000.00 "
PA,"$2,560,000.00 "
VT,"$5,120,000.00 "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove all the offending characters before pivoting:

```
df.Revenue = df.Revenue.str.replace(r'\$|,', '').astype(float)
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. Can you explain what the (r'\$|,', ' ') is actually doing?

Comment: It is a regular expression. Please read the `replace` documentation. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html